# Script to find empty files in the current directory?

Tags: command-line, files

Im trying to write a script that can search the current directory for empty files, followed by a count of the empty files. I would also prefer the files to be one per line of the output. For example the program output would look like:

```
Empty files are:
file1.pdf
file4.cpp
example-file
Number of empty files: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to recurse (i.e. descend into / count empty files inside subdirectories) then you can just use standard file tests e.g.

```
n=0
for f in *; do 
  [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ ! -s "$f" ]] && { echo "$f"; ((n++)); } 
done 
echo "Number of empty files: $n"
```

From `help test`:

```
  -f FILE        True if file exists and is a regular file.
  -s FILE        True if file exists and is not empty.
```

Comment: thank you, now if i wanted to make this same program but make it possible to specify a directory as an argument and if no argument is given use the current directory?

Comment: @TaylorStevens it's really just a matter of checking the number of positional parameters `$#` and acting accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` command to look for empty files

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
```

Where

- `-maxdepth 1` only look in current directory and not subdirectories
- `-type f` looks only for files, not directories
- `-empty` checks for empty files
- `tee /dev/tty` send filename to the terminal and to wc
- `wc -l` count the files

See `man find` for more information.

Comment: `/path/to/dest` is awkward in an answer to a question about a script to find empty files in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Size of the empty file is typically zero.
So running the following script will help to find the empty files

`find /home/ -type f -size oc -exec ls {} \;`

As units you can use:

```
b – for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
c – for bytes
w – for two-byte words
k – for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
M – for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
G – for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)
```

i created some empty files and kept it in the following directory

`/home/um/Documents/hello`

Now lets see all the empty files that i have created

`cd /home/um/Documents/hello` This command changes the directory to hello

`ls -sh` It list all the files including the size in human readable format in  `/home/um/Documents/hello`

> 16K empty.odt   12K empty.pdf  8.0K empty.txt   16K excel.ods

However the size of these files are in the range of 0 - 20 kb I am sure these  file are empty

So it is possible to sort all files based on size.

`find /home/um/Documents/hello -type pdf -size -20k -exec ls -lh {} \;`

It sort all the files that are lesser than 20kb